# prestashop SSL configuration

Tags: ssl, https, prestashop

I bought ssl certificate for our ecommerce web site. Certificate is successfully loaded on the server by the hosting company. They say that it is properly installed. I asked the the company who generated the ssl certificate for us to check if the certificate is loaded properly by the hosting firm and they checked they say that everything is ok they can see that the certificate is loaded succesfully. 
Our hosting is a shared hosting. The server is not dedicated to our usage only. 
Next I tried to activate ssl usage on prestashop by clicking EnableSSL under Preferences/General. 
Or I change ps_configuration SSL_ENABLED attribute
I have more than one problem when I enable SSL.

This is the normal view of our main page.
[image]
when I try to reach main url using https://www.lsvdukkan.com My view is turns out to be a total mess propably scripts do not work 
This is the messed up view of the main page :[image]

Running main page in https is not important for me. Important thing is enabling SSL after login and during payment. 
Second problem is when I enable ssl in prestashop , prestashop tries to direct customers to https page after login to the page https://www.lsvdukkan.com/my-account. But the page can not be found. It says there are multiple directions (direction loops) in the page ????? So it does not work. I informed the hosting firm about this direction problem after enabling prestashop but they don't have any idea of the problem. They say that ssl certificate is successfully loaded. Since they are not familiar with prestashop they don't have any idea on the problem. This is the view of the redirection problem. [image]
I tried to find a solution in the forums. I would appreciate very much if someone could help to use SSL certificate with prestashop. 
FERDA

Comment: Your SSL certificate works fine and it's properly installed. The problem is that your theme (or some modules) are not designed to work with SSL cetrtificates. More precisely even if you load the pages with https:// some of the resources are specified as http:// and the browser blocks that resources, since the site is trying to load insecure resources in secure (SSL/https) page. There's no simple solution to that problem. Contact the developer that have designed the theme and the modules and ask him to finish his job, or hire another developer to do that for you.

Comment: The problem is there is no developer for this template. This web site is for an NGO. A company which I met in a forum related to prestashop gaved this template for us. This one was one of the old templates that they were using sometimes ago. I am not sure they are using it anymore. They try to helped us sometimes during installation of the project but I know that they already have too much work of themselves. And since we are not their official customers I cannot ask them to change a template (this may take too much time) :(

Comment: Can you please give some more information? If the problem is related to links etc. I can try to change them with relative paths etc. Is it something more difficult ?

Comment: Then my advice is first to check the template and fix the resources that are being loaded by http instead of https on SSL pages. A lot of things are not ok. Even baseDir and baseUrl javascript variables are with http, instead of https and a lot of other resources, css, js, etc..

Comment: in addition to PretaShop-Developer.com, you might want to visit http://www.whynopadlock.com/ this will show you insecure items, those that are using http only

Comment: I looked to find something bad in the configuration and files myself but I couldn't fiind anything yet. I also talked with the company who gave the template to me. They are using the same template in 2 other sites. One of them is https://modavemarka.com/tr/. In those sites there is no problem. But I checked with the company who generated the certificate they say that the certificates which is used in https://modavemarka.com/tr/ is not a proper certificate (it checks only domain name and do nothing else ) so we can not take it as a base. Thank you for the whynopadlock.com website.

Comment: I just checked for whynopadlock web site. It shows lots of things. I will run it with the 2 other sites using the same template and maybe I can find something.

Comment: Most of the links which are shown by whynopadlock are picture links.. Should I have to regenerate the pictures in the sites after I loaded the ssl certificate?If so it maybe the reason of the problem because I didn't do that..

Comment: When I change the img paths in the css file from (../../img/sprites.png) to (https://www.lsvdukkan/themes/trendy/img/sprites.png)the number of insecure items decreases in whynopadlock but is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: The problem is in the frontcontroller.php. How did you activated ssl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this after looking for a good fix for this issue and wanted to share since I found this link before I found the base issue:

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/commit/640100f10f789129dc50a0d68e3e82cedf85aad3

Made this change in 1.5.6.2 and it fixed all the errors and everything is in the green now!

Hope this helps others...

-James

Comment: Hi James,I changed the line. It didn't caused an extra error. Later I enabled SSL. My main page looks allright after enabling SSL however when I try to login https page https://www.lsvdukkan.com/my-account does not come. It gives this error in Http,  ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I am not sure maybe this fixes the mess main page problem but not the second one. If you have any other suggestions I will be happy trying :) Thank you

Comment: @Ferda-Ozdemir-Sonmez: same problem here: did you maybe solve? How?

Comment: @Stratboy I am not responsible for that project for a while I moved on so I can not check  or make suggestions for that problem, sorry...

Comment: Hi sungodd, can you please upvote the question. I have issues related to the number of questions with 0 votes. This problem causes me not entering new questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some technical knowledge, you need to verify what resources like js scripts, css files, etc are loading out of the https, this may be caused by some modules that load this resources as absolute urls beginning by http://.

To solve the problem you should debug all resources that are loading in the wrong way, to do that you for example in Google Chrome you can use: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, there you will be able to see a list of "blocked" content, that blocked content are the resources you need to fix the way they load in your website.

I have done a quick check and retrieved this list:

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/css/css/default_styles.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):82
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%20Sans:400,300,700,normal': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):86
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/css/css/responsive.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):90
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/js/js/common.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):1
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/js/js/jquery.flexslider.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):1
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/css/css/flexslider.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):94
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/js/js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):1
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/css/css/cloud-zoom.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):96
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/js/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):1
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/js/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):100
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/js/js/fancybox.setting.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):1
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/js/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):102
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/js/js/jquery.tweet.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):1
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/js/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):1
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/js/js/jquery.accordion.source.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):1
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/js/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):1
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/css/css/bootstrap-tooltip.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):109
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/js/js/script.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):1
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.lsvdukkan.com/themes/trendy/js/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):1
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/l…8&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=false&header=false': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 (index):1022
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.losev.org.tr/images/image/Galleries/2010/tanitim_artikkimseyiuzmesin/tanitim_artikkimseyiuzmesin.swf': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
4
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.lsvdukkan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.losev.org.tr/images/image/Galleries/2010/tanitim_artikkimseyiuzmesin/tanitim_artikkimseyiuzmesin.swf': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

So, you now you just need to fix. Changing in absolute urls from http:// to // or relative urls.

Hope this help.

Best wishes,
Luis

Answer (score 0):

ADVANCED PARAMETERS - PERFORMANCE
and Compress section must be like this---

Smart cache for CSS - (NO)
Smart cache for javaScript - (NO)
Minify HTML - YES (usable)
Compress inline Javascript in HTML - (NO)
Apache optimization - YES (usable)